# In how many ways can $14$ people be seated in a row if there are $8$ men and they must sit next to one another?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

In how many ways can 14 people be seated in a row if:

a.) there are 7 men and 7 women and no two men or two women sit next to each other?

**My attempt:** Since no two men or women can sit next to each other I calculated $(7-1)! \cdot (7-1)! = 518400$

b.) there are 8 men and they must sit next to one another?

**My attempt:** If 8 men must sit next to one another, then there are 6 women left. What I did was calculate $(6 + 1)! = 5040$

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the number of permutations of $n$ distinct objects is $n!$ (not $(n-1)!$ or $(n+1)!$).

For (a). The 7 men and the 7 women are alternated and the row can start with a man or with a woman (2 cases). Therefore the number of ways is
$$2\cdot 7!\cdot 7!$$

For (b). We have a block of 8 men and 6 women, and the last man in the block can be in position $8$th to $14$th (7 cases). Therefore the number of ways is
$$7\cdot 8!\cdot 6!$$

Comment: Thank you, I see where my thinking went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For b. you forgot to permute men so you have to multiply it by $8!$, so it is $8!\cdot 7!$

For a. Why do you have $6!^2$?, you have 7 men and 7 women, so it is $7!\cdot 7! \cdot 2$, since you can start with a man or you start with a woman.